# Automating Date Range while extracting

Tags: python-2.7, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

The below script I am using to extract data from Google Analytics. Here I am extracting data for last one week. I want to automate the date range so that i don't have to change date_range every week.
I also want to avoid sampling of data by GA. Please guide my the correct way to automate in details.

**author** = 'test@gmail.com (test)'

```
import argparse
import sys
import csv
import string
import datetime
import json
import time

from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError

cam_name = sys.argv[1:]

class SampledDataError(Exception): pass

def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv[0], 'analytics', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/analytics.readonly')

  # Try to make a request to the API. Print the results or handle errors.
  try:
    profile_id = profile_ids[profile]
    if not profile_id:
      print ('Could not find a valid profile for this user.')
    else:      
      metrics = argv[1]
      dimensions = argv[2]
      reportName = argv[3]
      sort = argv[4]
      filters = argv[5]

      for start_date, end_date in date_ranges:
        limit = ga_query(service, profile_id, 0,
                                 start_date, end_date, metrics, dimensions, sort, filters).get('totalResults')
        for pag_index in range(0, limit, 10000):
          results = ga_query(service, profile_id, pag_index,
                                     start_date, end_date, metrics, dimensions, sort, filters)
          # if results.get('containsSampledData'):

            # raise SampledDataError
          print_results(results, pag_index, start_date, end_date, reportName)

  except TypeError as error:    
    # Handle errors in constructing a query.
    print ('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

  except HttpError as error:
    # Handle API errors.
    print ('Arg, there was an API error : %s : %s' %
           (error.resp.status, error._get_reason()))

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    # Handle Auth errors.
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run '
           'the application to re-authorize')

  except SampledDataError:
    # force an error if ever a query returns data that is sampled!
    print ('Error: Query contains sampled data!')


def ga_query(service, profile_id, pag_index, start_date, end_date, metrics, dimensions, sort, filters):

   return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date=start_date,
      end_date=end_date,
      metrics=metrics,
      dimensions=dimensions,
      sort=sort,
      filters=filters,
      samplingLevel='HIGHER_PRECISION',
      start_index=str(pag_index+1),
      max_results=str(pag_index+10000)).execute()


def print_results(results, pag_index, start_date, end_date, reportName):
  """Prints out the results.

  This prints out the profile name, the column headers, and all the rows of
  data.

  Args:
    results: The response returned from the Core Reporting API.
  """

  # New write header
  if pag_index == 0:
    if (start_date, end_date) == date_ranges[0]:
      print  ('Profile Name: %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName'))
      columnHeaders = results.get('columnHeaders')
      cleanHeaders = [str(h['name']) for h in columnHeaders]
      writer.writerow(cleanHeaders)
    print (reportName,'Now pulling data from %s to %s.' %(start_date, end_date))


  # Print data table.
  if results.get('rows', []):
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      for i in range(len(row)):
        old, new = row[i], str()
        for s in old:
          new += s if s in string.printable else ''
        row[i] = new
      writer.writerow(row)

  else:
    print ('No Rows Found')

  limit = results.get('totalResults')
  print (pag_index, 'of about', int(round(limit, -4)), 'rows.')
  return None

# Uncomment this line & replace with 'profile name': 'id' to query a single profile
# Delete or comment out this line to loop over multiple profiles.

#Brands

profile_ids = {'abc-Mobile': '12345',
                'abc-Desktop': '23456',
                'pqr-Mobile': '34567',
                'pqr-Desktop': '45678',
                'xyz-Mobile': '56789',
                'xyz-Desktop': '67890'}

date_ranges = [
('2017-01-24','2017-01-24'),
('2017-01-25','2017-01-25'),
('2017-01-26','2017-01-26'),
('2017-01-27','2017-01-27'),
('2017-01-28','2017-01-28'),
('2017-01-29','2017-01-29'),
('2017-01-30','2017-01-30')
]

for profile in sorted(profile_ids):
  print("Sequence 1",profile)
  with open('qwerty.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    for getThisReport in d["Reports"]:
      print("Sequence 2",getThisReport["ReportName"])
      reportName = getThisReport["ReportName"]
      metrics = getThisReport["Metrics"]
      dimensions = getThisReport["Dimensions"]
      sort = getThisReport["sort"]
      filters = getThisReport["filter"]

      path = 'C:\\Projects\\DataExport\\test\\' #replace with path to your folder where csv file with data will be written

      today = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')

      filename = profile+'_'+reportName+'_'+today+'.csv' #replace with your filename. Note %s is a placeholder variable and the profile name you specified on row 162 will be written here
      with open(path + filename, 'wt') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter = '|', lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        args = [sys.argv,metrics,dimensions,reportName,sort,filters]
        if __name__ == '__main__': main(args)
      print ( "Profile done. Next profile...")

print ("All profiles done.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate) supports some interesting things as far as dates goes.

> All Analytics data requests must specify a date range. If you do not include start-date and end-date parameters in the request, the server returns an error. Date values can be for a specific date by using the pattern YYYY-MM-DD or relative by using today, yesterday, or the NdaysAgo pattern. Values must match [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo).

so doing something like

```
start_date = '7daysAgo' 
end_date   = 'today'
```

Just remember that data hasn't completed processing for 24 - 48 hours so your data for today, yesterday and the day before that may not be 100% accurate.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by Last & days.    There is no way to fully avoid sampling its based upon the amount of data in your account and the amount of data that will be returned by the request.    You must have a very large account if you sample with only 7 days worth of data.

Comment: If i put start_date & end_date like you mention above, GA will sample the data.
I need data from yesterday to last 7 days,  is it possible that I put date_range like the following:
date_ranges = [
('yesterday','yesterday'),
('2daysAgo','2daysAgo'),
('3daysAgo','3daysAgo'),
('4daysAgo','4daysAgo'),
('5daysAgo','5daysAgo'),
('6daysAgo','6daysAgo'),
('7daysAgo','7daysAgo')
]

Comment: You can do it how ever you want but remember each one is going to be a call against your quota.   What you are suggesting is however what I currently use for some of my bigger clients.

Comment: Note: If you switch to the Google analytics API v4 there is a field called isgolden  which is returned and will tell you if the data in your request has completed processing or not.

Comment: So is there any difference in data you encounter when you put both the date_range like I mention above(manual date_range and automated one)?

Comment: None with the exception of the fact that your not sampling anymore.   And you need to remember to always over write data for the last two days.  As its not completed processing.    Really I normally select data starting 3days - 1days.   I run nightly and over write yesterdays data every night.  This way my customers have data they can work with for the last two days and it just gets refreshed until its over 72 hours old then we leave it.

Comment: I am working on Google analytics API v4 only, will you please elaborate how to use field called isDataGolden?
Example will surely help me understand exactly.
Thanks For your precious time

Comment: Your code is using Google Analytics V3 not Google analytics v4.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#reportdata isDataGolden boolean Indicates if response to this request is golden or not. Data is golden when the exact same request will not produce any new results if asked at a later point in time.

Comment: Python examples for google analytics v4 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples